# QgsVectorFileWriter not working PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, geometry, fields-attributes, vector-layer

I need to write the attribute of all layers with geometries and without geometries
I am able to write layers with geometries but cant write the ones without geometry.

[image]

I used `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` function it works for the linetest layer but not working for the test I want to export test attribute table as CSV I have attached the code I used below.

```
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(filename, "line_test", "ogr")
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(filename,"test","ogr")
# this works and saves the csv 
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1,"outpath/line_text.csv","utf-8",driverName = "CSV" , layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
# below line works but saves the same content as above not the test layer content
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer2,"outpath/test.csv","utf-8",driverName = "CSV" , layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

How can I get the content and export it?

Comment: Hi, I think the problem lies in your first 2 lines of code as they both reference the same variable 'filename' which isn't changed between its use in defining layer1 and layer2

Comment: no the same file has two layers mentioned above

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the filename variable?

Comment: https://file.io/OqwfeF0jOD04  have attached the qgis ldf

Comment: Thanks, as you say it shows that you have 2 layers in the project, but it doesn't show what is happening to the variable in your code. Can you share the rest of your code?

Comment: i just defined the variable filename and reading the file from local path that's it.

Comment: What geometry type is layer `test`?

Comment: @alphabetasoup it has no geometry its a dbf file format.

Comment: Then why did you state `'GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'` in your `layerOptions` parameter?

Comment: then what are we supposed to give ?.